# Can I colour individual points with stacked columns in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got a chart built using 3 series arrays, each with 5 points of data, displayed as a stacked column chart for each of 5 unique products. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaLiTHkA/rbx9h3r5/) for a de-branded exampled.

For all my research so far, it seems the `plotOptions.column.colorByPoints` option is the most likely solution to this, but it's only getting me half way there.

Following the series structure, I need the chart colours to match the following structure:

```
[ /* note: this example uses pseudo colours */
  [transparent,  transparent,   transparent, transparent,    transparent],
  [lighter-blue, lighter-green, lighter-red, lighter-yellow, grey],
  [blue,         green,         red,         yellow,         black]
]
```

Unfortunately, setting colours for each series does not help because each point in the series needs to be different.

For the record, the `plotOptions.column.color` option associated with `colorByPoints` only seems to accept one array (a nested array matching the data structure does not work here), but it applies to each stack as a whole, so setting a single array of 15 colours in my case only makes use of the first 5.

This is perplexing me, am I missing something silly here or is this simply not possible with Hichcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to supply the color in the data point object.

ie:

```
data: [
  {y:15, color:'blue'}, 
  {y:64, color:'red'}
]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/rbx9h3r5/3/

Comment: Thanks for that.. Between your answer and the various research I've done since asking this question, it seems the only way is to set each and every point's colour. I was hoping for a slightly more abstract way to do it.. I'll just make a little wrapper function myself to assign these colours to my data from an array. :)